# Issues in using a internet browser with java plugin on Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox, java, google-chrome, chromium, plugins

Despite I followed various instructions/replies indicated in various answers on Askubuntu, I can't in any way use Java plugins in Firefox 71.0 on my Linux Ubuntu 18.04 (Linux 4.15.0-74-generic # 84-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 08:06: 28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU / Linux).

Do you have any solution to solve this issue?

I encounter the same issue using the chromium browser (Google Chrome 79.0.3945.88). Can anyone tell me how to fix this other issue?

Alternatively can someone point me to a browser that can use the Java Oracle plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of early 2017, the java plugin is no longer compatible with Mozilla Firefox and Google Chome. Oracle only supports Microsoft InternetExplorer and Apple Safari.